# C# console and windows application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, console

Is there any way to run both windows and console application while debugging C# project in Visual Studio 2013? I'm trying to run an XNA project if that helps in any way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same solution you can set multiple projects on startup in the solution properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could build one of them and run the executable directly from the debug folder while debugging the other project. Alternatively there's some information here on switching between processes while debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx

Comment: I'm gonna check that link, it might be just what I need in the future. Thanks a lot.